# When to use Parasitic Constructor Pattern

Tags: javascript

Why should Parasitic constructor pattern be used with caution and when it would be appropriate to use that pattern?

Comment: why did you delete your old question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495720/when-to-use-parasitic-constructor-pattern

Comment: For reference, it would be helpful to provide a link or an example.

Comment: @Priya to be honest I have never heard of such a pattern and my trusty google couldn't find anything called a parasitic constructor pattern.

Comment: seriously, WTF is a Parasitic constructor pattern ?

Comment: See Parasitic Inheritance here: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html

Comment: oh that explains why i dont know the term.

Comment: In the YUI Theater videos Crockford recommends using Parasitic Inheritance when possible, because it allows you to implement information hiding, and privileged methods.   As far as caution, I'm not sure, maybe anytime you **NEED** multiple inheritance?

Comment: I recommend you stop reading crap and use common sense - does that count ?

Comment: I think Crockford's talks are interesting for you to understand JS and how it works, intellectual teasers. In my real code I use prototypical inheritance (imitating classical inheritance) and mixins whenever I need something like multiple inheritance.

Comment: @f00 - This is a fairly well-known term/pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is going to be largely a matter of style and opinion. YMMV. But there's a few issues involved I can think of.

The biggest one is that you're likely in one of two edge cases. Either the "class" you're creating with the Parasitic Constructor is going to be instantiated a very small number of times (1, maybe 2) -- in which case you might as well just instantiate the "superclass" and augment it with a given method manually -- or you're going to be instantiating it a larger number of times in which case having your extra method exist in a prototype object is going to yield some efficiency gains.

I'd also add that deep class structures in general have an overhead. Defining a class that's "everything this other class has BUT with JUST ONE MORE METHOD" means you're adding a layer to your hierarchy for one little detail. Maybe necessary sometimes, but it's also possibly a warning flag that your class hierarchy may not be designed effectively in the first place.

(I'd also note that if you read the entire [link wsanville mentioned in the comments](http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html), you'll see at the end that Crockford states more or less that he's realized the classical model, particularly involving a proliferative and/or deep hierarchy, is often unnecessary in JavaScript and possibly even "a mistake." This often matches my experience. There are problem domains where modeling using a hierarchy of classes still feels natural, and it's good to know the various techniques for supporting that easily in JavaScript, but it's often effective to stick to prototypical objects and functions as well.)